# Host server stops processing php scripts after i cancel a debug session on my local IIS

Tags: php, web-services, curl

So I have 2 web services

I receive an XML message from an outside source to my PHP web service
which looks like this (this web service is hosted on an online host provider)

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ){ 
    $postText = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
}
```

and I send this XML to a local web service in C#

```
    $url = "http://dynamicip:localport/Request.asmx/Request";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "xml=".$clean_xml);
    $content=curl_exec($ch);
    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    echo $content;
```

Now everything is okay except when I debug my local c# web service and I stop it in the middle of processing the XML file, which means the service doesn't send back a response.

As a result, the online hosting server stops processing any PHP file for hours.

Is there anything I can improve in my PHP code that will prevent this from happening?

Comment: Ugh, sounds like you have something hardcoded, that is comunicating with your production system ... just a guess, though!

Comment: Have you looked at implementing any timeouts on the web service? Sounds like something is hanging during processing. What's the relevant code for the online service?

Comment: I applied a timeout now. I will have to test it when my server starts processing PHP files again.